# Is zero a limit point of the sequence $(\sqrt n \sin n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is zero a limit point of the sequence $(\sqrt n \sin n)_n$?

Comment: What do you think? How many terms of the sequence around some small neighbour of $0$ can you find?

Comment: Seems like I didn't understood the question.

Comment: Did you get something from an answer below?

Answer (score 11):

By [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), $\pi$ can be approximated by rationals $p/n$ so that $|n\pi-p|<\frac{1}{n}$. Since sine is 1-Lipschitz,  we get$|\sin(p)|<\frac{1}{n}$ from which the result is immediate.

Comment: Which makes one wonder whether the OP will manage to complete the step going from $|\sin(p)|\lt\frac1n$ for some $p$s to $|\sin(n)|\lt\frac{c}n$ for some $n$s.