# Is zero a limit point of the sequence $n \sin \sqrt n$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is zero a limit point of the sequence $(n \sin \sqrt n)$?

My attempt:

Considering [@MikhailKatz' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/390335/409) to the question ["Is zero a limit point of the sequence $(\sqrt{n}\sin n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390327/409):

> By [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), $\pi$ can be approximated by rationals $p/n$ so that $|n\pi-p|<\frac{1}{n}$. Since sine is 1-Lipschitz, we get $\left|\sin(p)\right|<\frac{1}{n}$ from which the result is immediate.

is it then valid to write the following here?

> By [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), $\pi$ can be approximated by rationals $p/n$ so that $|n\pi-p|<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$. Since sine is 1-Lipschitz,  we get $\left|\sin(p)\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ from which the result is immediate.

Can I conclude that $0$ is a limit point?

Comment: I'm confused.  How do you go from $|\sin(p)|<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$  to $|n\sin{\sqrt{n}}|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @saulspatz  $(n \sin \sqrt n) <  \frac {n }{ \sqrt n \sqrt n \sqrt n}$

Comment: Did you just copy https://math.stackexchange.com/a/390335 ?

Comment: @jasmine I really don't see how that works

Comment: @ChrisCulter yes  i just  copy  ..actually i also don't  know  the  actual logics

Comment: Well, my first thought is to avoid overusing the letter $n$. Only introduce it towards the end of the argument.

Comment: In fact, if $0<a<1/2$ then $0$ is a limit point of $n^a\sin(\sqrt n)$. This can be done by considering $n=m^2$.

Answer (score 2):

#### Partial result only (too long for a comment and I will go to bed now):

I will use the following heavy machinery:

**Theorem.** (*Weyl/equidistribution of polynomial sequences*) Let $$P(n)=a_dn^d+a_{d-1}+\dots+a_0$$ be a polynomial where $a_d$ is irrational. Then the sequence $(\{P(n)\})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) in $[0,1[$. (Here, $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part.)

---

In particular, we know that the squence $(\{m^2\pi^2\})_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1[$, so for all $\varepsilon>0$, (here, $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality) $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{|\big\{\{\pi^2\},\{2^2\pi^2\},\dots,\{m^2\pi^2\}\big\}|
\cap[0,\varepsilon]
}{m}
= \varepsilon.$$

This means that, "on average", one out of $\frac1\varepsilon$ members of $m^2\pi^2$ is at most $\varepsilon$ away from the greatest integer from below. (Note that, heuristically, we want $n\cdot\sin(\sqrt n)\approx 0$, so $\sqrt n\approx m\cdot\pi$ for some integer $m$ and thus $m^2\cdot\pi^2$ should be close to an integer.)

**Lemma.** Let $\{m^2\pi^2\}<\varepsilon$ and $n=\lfloor m^2\pi^2\rfloor$. Then $n\cdot\sin(\sqrt n)\in[-n\sqrt \varepsilon, n\sqrt \varepsilon]$.

*Proof.* We have (note  that $\sqrt{m^2-\varepsilon}=\sqrt{m+\sqrt\varepsilon}\sqrt{m-\sqrt\varepsilon}>m-\sqrt\varepsilon$) $$\sqrt n = \sqrt{m^2\pi^2-\{m^2\pi^2\}}\in[\sqrt{m^2-\varepsilon},m\pi]\subset[m-\sqrt \varepsilon,m\pi].$$

Since $\sin$ is $1$-Lipschitz, we have $$\sin(\sqrt n)\in[-\sqrt \varepsilon,\sqrt\varepsilon].$$ This achieves a proof. $\square$

---

Now I would like to conclude saying that $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily small. **But**, $n$ depends on $m$ and thus on $\varepsilon$ and can get really large before $\{m^2\pi^2\}<\varepsilon$. It seems that some further quantification of "how fast the series becomes equidistributed is needed."

*Remark.* I am not even sure if $0$ actually is a limit point. A converse result may also be provable using a similar approach as mine from above.

Comment: @jasmine Please don't mark this as an answer (yet) because it does not answer your question 